# Angular 8 ng-bootstrap table header keyboard navigation on sort columns

Tags: angular, accessibility, keyboard-events, ng-bootstrap, wai-aria

I am building a data table with sortable headers, as shown in this [example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable) in the documentation.

**Problem**

The sortable table headers must have keyboard navigation enabled for accessibility. The table headers  must be selectable with a tab focus and the selected column must trigger the sort function when the enter button is pressed. That way the sort can be used with keyboard navigation only (without requiring a mouse).

Versions:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
```

**Attempts**

I tried adding a tab index to the th element, which makes the element tab focused. However, pressing the enter button does not trigger the sort function.

```
<th scope="col" tabindex="0" sortable="name" (sort)="onSort($event)">Country</th>
```

I also tried adding the (keydown) method, but the keyboard event is not assignable to the sort event, and will not work since it does not pass in the column and direction parameters.

```
<th scope="col" tabindex="0" sortable="name" (keydown)="onSort($event)" (sort)="onSort($event)">Country</th>

Argument of type 'KeyboardEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SortEvent'.
Type 'KeyboardEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'SortEvent': column, direction
```

**Example**

Here is a stackblitz with the full code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-db3bux-g2z44n?file=src/app/table-complete.html

Comment: One way would be to add @HostListener to your directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added @HostListener and tried your stackblitz seems to be working

```
export class NgbdSortableHeader {
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(e.which === 13) { //only react to "Enter"
       this.rotate();
    }
  }

  @Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';
  @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
  @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

  rotate() {
    this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
    this.sort.emit({column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great start but it doesn't seem to be actually triggering the sort function when pressing enter. The stackblitz has been updated.

Comment: my bad, has to be just ['$event'], updating answer